# Prove that $\sqrt[m]{k}$ is irrational whenever k is not an mth power of some integer.

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Let the coefficients of the polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + x^m$ be integers. Then any real root of the polynomial is either integral or irrational.
(a) Explain why the Lemma immediately implies that $\sqrt[m]{k}$ is irrational whenever
k is not an mth power of some integer.
(b) Carefully prove the Lemma.

This is problem 1.19 of Mathematics for Computer Science (MIT 6.042j). I am self studying the subject and this question tripped me up.

How is the implication in part (a) related to the polynomial?
I tried messing with sum / product of roots of a polynomial but that seems like a dead end. Also, I already proved previously that square root of a prime number is irrational.

Comment: In (a) you don't have any information about $x$. So the statement isn't true e.g, $\sqrt[e]{42^e} = 42$ is a counter-example. Are you sure you have quoted the problem correctly?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes I messed up the mathjax. Editied.

Answer (score 1):

The lemma is the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) for monic polynomials. I'll sketch the solution:

(a) Consider $x^m-k$.

(b) If $x=p/q$ for coprime $p\in\Bbb Z,\,q\in\Bbb N$ then $\sum_{i=0}^ma_ip^iq^{n-i}=0$ with $a_m:=1$. All but one term is obviously a multiple of $p$, so $p|a_0$; all but one term is obviously a multiple of $q$, so $q|a_m$, i.e. $q=1$.